# InnoScript - The shortcut asks for UAC?

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, admin, uac, shortcut-file

I am creating an installer in InnoScript. I am facing an issue. I use the following code to create the shortcuts,

```
Name: "{commonstartmenu}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyIcon.ico"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyIcon.ico"
```

On Windows 10 the created icons shows the UAC shield icon and asks the user the UAC message to run as administrator when opened.

This does not happen in Windows 7. It runs without asking UAC message.

How to prevent from showing the UAC message in Windows 10?

Comment: If you create a shared shortcut to the same program manually, does it behave differently?

Comment: Same issue when created manually.

Comment: OK, so why do you ask about Inno Setup? What is the application that you create a shortcut to? Does the problem happen only with that specific application?

Comment: The installer was previously created with Visual Studio and it did not ask for UAC when the shortcuts are opened.

Comment: This seems to be happening to this application only.

Comment: Again, what is the application? Did you create it yourself? Or is it a 3rd party application?

Comment: I found the issue. It seems the installation directory already existed with limited user access. This why it asked for UAC. When another folder location was selected, it did not ask for UAC. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the installation directory already existed with limited user access. This is why it asked for UAC. When another folder location was selected, it did not ask for UAC.